# Bootstrap 5: align icon and text within Button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to align icons and text in a modal body:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="d-grid gap-2" id="someButtons">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I add the buttons:

```
testItems.forEach(function ( item ) {
    let btn = document.createElement("a");
    btn.setAttribute("role", "button");
    btn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> ${item}`;
    ["btn", "btn-primary"].forEach(item => btn.classList.add(item)); 
    btnsDiv.appendChild(btn)
});
```

I also tried this:

```
let delBtn = document.createElement("a");
    delBtn.setAttribute("role", "button");
    ["btn", "btn-danger"].forEach(item => delBtn.classList.add(item)); 
    delBtn.innerHTML = `<p class="text-start"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></p>`
    btnsDiv.appendChild(delBtn)
```

[image]

can I achieve this with bootstrap5 alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your delete button, `.text-start` is the key but it should be applied to the buttons. You can also remove the `<p>`. In the following snippet I have also added `.me-2` to the icons to give them some right margin to match the spacing you have in your desired output image.

```js
let testItems = ['one', 'two', 'three']
let btnsDiv = document.getElementById('someButtons')
testItems.forEach(function(item) {
  let btn = document.createElement("a");
  btn.setAttribute("role", "button");
  btn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-plus-circle me-2"></i> ${item}`;
  ["btn", "btn-primary", "text-start"].forEach(item => btn.classList.add(item));
  btnsDiv.appendChild(btn)
});
let delBtn = document.createElement("a");
delBtn.setAttribute("role", "button");
["btn", "btn-danger", "text-start"].forEach(item => delBtn.classList.add(item));
delBtn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-minus-circle me-2"></i> some text`
btnsDiv.appendChild(delBtn)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="d-grid gap-2" id="someButtons">
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add bootstrap `d-flex` with `justify-content-start` and `align-items-center` classes to your buttons, this will make them flex and add a `justify-content` property set to ***start*** on the content in the button.

If you set up an object with the names as keys, you can nest another object with the buttons type and icon as key/value pairs and reference them in a `for ... in` loop using `Object.keys(btnObj[i]` and `Object.keys(btnObj[i].`

```js
const btnObj = {
  'one': {
    'fa-plus-circle': 'btn-primary'
  },
  'two': {
    'fa-plus-circle': 'btn-primary'
  },
  'three': {
    'fa-plus-circle': 'btn-primary'
  },
  'some text': {
    'fa-minus-circle': 'btn-danger'
  }
}

for (let i in btnObj) {
  let btn = document.createElement("a");
  btn.setAttribute("role", "button");
  btn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas ${Object.keys(btnObj[i])}"></i>&nbsp;${i}`;
  ["btn", `${Object.values(btnObj[i])}`, "d-flex", "justify-content-start", "align-items-center"].forEach(item => btn.classList.add(item));
  document.getElementById('someButtons').appendChild(btn)
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="d-grid gap-2" id="someButtons">
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btnsDiv = document.getElementById("someButtons");
const testItems = ["Hi","Hello"];

testItems.forEach(function ( item ) {
    let btn = document.createElement("a");
    btn.setAttribute("role", "button");
    btn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-plus-circle me-2"></i> ${item}`;
    ["btn", "btn-primary", "text-start"].forEach(item => btn.classList.add(item)); 
    btnsDiv.appendChild(btn);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="d-grid gap-2" id="someButtons">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding the "text-start" class, for more info see:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/